# form submission not working?

Tags: javascript, html, flask

I had this simple form.. where I was taking an input from user like the following

```
<form action="/data" autocomplete="on" method="POST">
  <input id="search" name="search" type="text" placeholder="Search for song or artists..">
<input id="search_submit" value="Submit" type="submit">
 </form>
```

And everything was working fine..

Now.. I wanted to add slider to it and send the slider value to python.
How do i do this?

I modified the form to this:

```
<form action="/data" autocomplete="on" method="POST">
  <input id="search" name="search" type="text" placeholder="Search for song or artists..">
    <input type="range" min="-1" max="1" value="0" step="0.05" onchange="showValue(this.value)" /><input id="search_submit" value="Submit" type="submit">
    <span id="range" style="color:#BDBDBD">0</span>
 </form>
```

But it is not working I get

```
Bad Request

The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
```

EDIT

```
@app.route("/data", methods=['POST'])
def entry_post():
    query = request.form["search"]
    print request.form["range"] # I just added this line in the code
```

Comment: Post the code form /data.

Comment: @CyberJunkie: Please take a look at edits

Comment: I think you're missing the "name" attribute for the range input in your html

Comment: @eugecm Yupp.. Got it.. that fixed it.. if you can add this comment to  the answer. I can accept it. :) Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the "name" attribute on the range input field.